# Is there a way to use a Scanner object to search a text document for specific data?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am making a program that reads data from a formatted text document:

> Planetary Data
>
> Planet       Diameter (km)      Mass (kg)      g (m/s^2)
>
> - Mercury           4880         3.30E+23           3.70
> - Venus            12104         4.87E+24           8.87
> - Earth            12756         5.97E+24           9.79
> - Mars              6794         6.24E+23           3.61
> - Jupiter         142984         1.90E+27          24.80
> - Saturn          120536         5.68E+26          10.43
> - Uranus           51118         8.68E+25           8.86
> - Neptune          49352         1.02E+26          11.17

In a text file it's a little more pretty but basically it is a four column document with info one number falling into each column. I am using the scanner class to try to read only the last column of numbers, but can't find an easy way to do it with out using a ton of nextLine() calls. Is there a better way to search just for those doubles, and pull them into an array with a scanner?

This code will compile but I get a mismatch error as soon as I run it.

```
public static double [] getGravity()throws IOException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("PlanetaryData.txt"));
    double [] getGrav = new double[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        getGrav[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
        getGrav[i] /= 10;
        System.out.println(getGrav[i]);
    }
    return getGrav;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your text file structure as below:

```
Mercury 4880 3.30E+23 3.70
Venus 12104 4.87E+24 8.87
Earth 12756 5.97E+24 9.79
Mars 6794 6.24E+23 3.61
Jupiter 142984 1.90E+27 24.80
Saturn 120536 5.68E+26 10.43
Uranus 51118 8.68E+25 8.86
Neptune 49352 1.02E+26 11.17
```

You may try this:

```
public static double [] getGravity()throws IOException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("PlanetaryData.txt"));
    double [] getGrav = new double[8];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        getGrav[i] = inFile.nextLine().split("\\s+")[3];
        System.out.println(getGrav[i]);
    }
    return getGrav;
}
```

Comment: There is a little more white space between each column in the real file but it's essentially the same.

Comment: then you can use `split("\\s+")`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is using a List of doubles to store your read graivty values with something like,

```
List<Double> al = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    if (str == null) {
      continue;
    }
    double gravity = Double.parseDouble(
        str.substring(1 + str.lastIndexOf(' ')).trim());
    al.add(gravity);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (scanner != null) {
    scanner.close();
  }
}
System.out.println(al);
```

However, then you have no direct link between planet name and value. Another option is using a `Map<String, Double>` to associate the planet name and value like,

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    if (str == null) {
      continue;
    }
    String planet = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' '));
    double gravity = Double.parseDouble(
        str.substring(1 + str.lastIndexOf(' ')).trim());
    map.put(planet, gravity);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (scanner != null) {
    scanner.close();
  }
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: meh. I'd like to say that I could use that, but I'm a beginning AP Comp Sci student so I don't really know lists or try or catch etc. I have an array with the planet names so that later it can be associated, but I wasn't required to grab it from the text file for the assignment. Thanks though!